# Can I get the table, column and type information from a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using ruby and activerecord to get information about a mysql table.

I was hoping I could get this information directly from my model class, is this possible?

Say I have my model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Is it now possible for me to get information regarding:

```
1. mysql table
2. columns
3. column types
```

Or do I have to look somewhere deeper into the ActiveRecord module to get this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. `Product.table_name`
2. `Product.column_names`
3. `Product.columns_hash['title'].type`

Comment: If you use the 3. with the 'id'
`Product.columns_hash["id"].type` gives you `:integer`
Is there a way to transform that into a `Integer` ??

Comment: `Product.columns_hash["id"].type.to_s.classify.constantize`

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [ActiveRecord::ModelSchema::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html):

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name # 1
  self.columns # 2
  self.columns_hash['name'].type # 3
end
```

Comment: Are you sure about the last one? Docs says that `columns` is an array, not a hash.